# How to Set Value in DataGridViewTextBoxCell in WindowForm c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

I can't set Value in DataGridViewTextBox

Here is my code

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tbCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxCell tbCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
tbCell.Value = "1";
tbCol.CellTemplate = tbCell;
tbCol.Name = "qtySelect";
tbCol.HeaderText = "เลือกจำนวน"; 

gridProduct.Columns.Add(tbCol);
```

When I Run Textbox are added but it's a blank textbox

any one can help me.

Thank.

Comment: It's not clear in the documentation, but I think the CellTemplate just provides the cell style, not the cell value.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
yourdatagridview["columnName", rowindex].Value = "Your value";
```

Answer (score 1):

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tbCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell tbCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

```
        // Used for the appearence of the cell, it doesn't mean that there is a correlation between the cell and the column (see below ***)
        tbCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        tbCol.CellTemplate = tbCell;

        tbCol.Name = "qtySelect";
        tbCol.HeaderText = "Header";

        int colIndex = gridProduct.Columns.Add(tbCol);
        const int rowNumber = 0;    // define which row you want

        //Pay attention that you may need to add rows before writting to the cell
        //const int rowNumber = 1;
        //gridProduct.Rows.Add();            

        gridProduct.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[colIndex].Value = "Value for cell";

        //*** If you want to work with the cell itself, you first need to get a reference to it
        //tbCell = gridProduct.Rows[0].Cells[0] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;
        //tbCell.Value = "1"; // and then you can overwrite the value
```